# Define struct having more than 40 fields using BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT in Boost::Hana

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-hana

Defining a struct that has more than 40 fields using macro BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT in library Boost::hana, for example,

```
#include <boost/hana/define_struct.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

// a simple struct having 41 fields
struct Foo {
    BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT(Foo,
        (int, bar_0),
        (int, bar_1),
        ...,
        (int, bar_40)
    );
};
```

will raise an compile error

```
pasting "BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT_IMPL_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token.
```

Looking deeply into the source code of Hana, one can found that in file `boost/hana/detail/struct_macros.hpp`,
all macros are defined with hard coded implements from a boilerplate,

```cpp
...
#define BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT_IMPL_40(TYPE , m1, m2, ..., m39) \
#define BOOST_HANA_DEFINE_STRUCT_IMPL_41(TYPE , m1, m2, m3, ..., m40) \
```

So my question is

1. How can I define a new max argument number, such as 128, and regenerate the macros, so that more arguments are able to pass?
2. Is it a good practice to use such a struct implemented by Hana tuple but having too many fields? If it is not a good design, what alternative is recommended?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you sure you actually want a struct of 40+ fields? None of them can be meaningfully grouped into nested structs?

Comment: @yurikilochek Thank you for your good point of design. The data is loaded from an upstream source, and the fields are of parallel meanings so that not convenient to be grouped. Technically, is it possible to increase the hana limit?

Comment: only the macro has the limitation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is boost/hana/detail/struct_macros.hpp.erb which can be used to regenerate boost/hana/detail/struct_macros.hpp using

```
MAX_NUMBER_OF_MEMBERS=55 erb struct_macros.hpp.erb > struct_macros.hpp
```